# MySQL select records that have all values of a column the same?

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine

I have been working on a product database schema and one of the requirements is that in order to consider a product as discontinued all of the product skus must be set to discontinued.

```
Product Table:
id
slug
name
```

One Product to Many ProductSkus

```
ProductSku Table
id
slug
name
product_id
product_sku_availability_id
```

One ProductSku to One ProductSkuAvailability

```
ProductSkuAvaliability
id
slug
name
```

now I don't really need an exact query, but is there a way to only select products where all  productSkus.product_sku_availability are discontinued? here is a sample of what I am asking:

```
| productId | productSkuId | availabilityId |
| 1         | 1            | 1              |
| 1         | 2            | 1              |
| 2         | 3            | 2              |
| 2         | 4            | 1              |
```

in the above sample I would only want to select the productId = 1 because both product skus have an availabilityId of 1.

Comment: somehow your `ProductSkuAvaliability` table seems a bit wrong. But a `GROUP BY productId` with `HAVING MIN(availabilityId) = 1 AND MAX(availabilityId) = 1` should do.

Comment: You are right that works! IF you want to format your comment as an answer I will mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the value of the column availabilityId has got the same value for every productId then are the maximum and minimum value equal. Because of that should a

```
GROUP BY productId
```

with

```
HAVING (MIN(availabilityId) = 1 AND MAX(availabilityId) = 1)
```

produce the desired result.